# Anonymous Firebase sign in method not working

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, fragment

really hoping someone can help me out here as I've been stuck for a few weeks with this and have no idea if I'm headed down the right path. My ultimate goal is to download images that I manually uploaded to my firebase storage and then retrieve and store the download urls in an array for passing to my fragment's recyclerview adapter.

I setup the necessary firebase implementations, configured the console, linked the android/firebase projects etc, and then drafted some code for downloading the images from storage. After many incorrect attempts of my own I went with some pretty standard code that I saw on firebase and SO articles.

But upon execution, the array would not fill and I would get a null pointer exception at the "mImageID.get(position)" in my onBindViewHolder() method shown below.

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: was called");

      
        if(mImageID.get(position) != null){
            Glide.with(viewHolder.imageItem.getContext())
                    .load(mImageID.get(position))
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .fallback(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(viewHolder.imageItem);
        }else if(mImageID.get(position) == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: image URLs not filled to array");
        }
```

I then noticed that the stack trace had a "no user authentication" warning prior to this exception even though my application doesn't have a sign in activity. I thought that might be the issue so I:

- Enabled anonymous sign in on console
- Setup FirebaseAuth and FirebaseUser variable
- Created a method to signInAnonymously
- The signInAnonymously method then triggers the download image Url method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started");
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.listView_view);

        //add array for each item
        mAuthor = new ArrayList<>();
        mTitle = new ArrayList<>();

        //authentication for Firebase access
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(mUser != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: User object not null");
            downloadFirebaseImages();
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: User object null, running anonymousAuth()");
            anonymousAuth();
        }
```

This removed the null pointer exception. However it doesn't seem to initate an anonymous sign in and subsequent imageURL download.

Basically it gets to the anonymousAuth() method but it doesn't run the signInAnonymously() method. What's weird is that even when attaching an onFailureListener, it doesn't print out the log.debug message within. So it's not like the task is failing. It's like it doesn't even run at all.

The logcat finishes here:
2021-02-13 19:24:22. D/LIST: onCreateView: started
2021-02-13 19:24:22. D/LIST: onCreateView: User object null, running anonymousAuth()

Thanks in advance for any assistance you could provide.

```
private void downloadFirebaseImages(){
        mImageURL = new ArrayList<>();
        mImagesRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "downloadFirebaseImage: attempted to fill image array");
            String imageRef = Integer.toString(i);
            mImagesRef.child(imageRef).getDownloadUrl()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            mImageURL.add(uri);
                            Log.d(TAG, "getDownloadUrl successful: added uri to arraylist");
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getDownloadUrl failed: unable to retrieve firebase images");
                }
            });
        }
        halter = false;
    }

    private void anonymousAuth() {
      mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
              Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously() succeeded: signed in anonymously");
              downloadFirebaseImages();
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

When `onComplete` is called it means that sign in **completed**,not necessarily that is *succeeded*.

You should check if the `task` succeeded, or use an `addOnSuccessListener`. The latter would look something like:

```
mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
      if (task.isSuccessfull()) {
          Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously() succeeded: signed in anonymously");
          downloadFirebaseImages();
      }
      else {
          Log.e(TAG, "signInAnonymously() failed", task.getException());
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Frank. I previously tried an onSuccessListener and neither  "signInAnonymously() succeeded: signed in anonymously" or  "signInAnonymously() failed" are printing to logcat with the above suggestion, so I'm still confused on this.